# errorwhile running flutter doctor --android-licenses

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

flutter doctor --android-licenses
Error: Could not find or load main class Singh\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\..
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Singh\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\//

Answer (score 0):

You need Android SDK Command Line Tools installed. If you're using Android Studio go in **Preferences -> Appearance & Behaviour -> System Settings -> Android SDK** then select the SKL tools tab and install the latest Android SDK Command Line Tools.